# Previous tab selection remains active after selecting another tab

Tags: android, material-design, material-components

I have a `TabLayout` that I would like to customize as follows:

- If a tab item is not selected only an icon is shown
- If a tab item is selected an icon and text should be shown

I have implemented a `OnTabSelectedListener` and set the text to `null` when the tab is not selected as selected. When I run the text on the 'unselected' tab is removed but the tab remains in an active state as shown in this image: [image]

**Code:**

```
tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{
            override fun onTabReselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                // If I remove this the problem is resolved.
                tab?.text = null
            }

            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
               tab?.text = "Selected"
            }

        })
```

**xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabInlineLabel="true"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabGravity="fill">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp"
        android:text="Selected" />
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp" />
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp"
        />
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp" />
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp"
        />

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

I have tried everything in my power to find a solution but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to go around the issue. I call `updateTabs()` in `onTabSelected()`. Here is the method:

```
private fun updateTabs(){
        for (i in 0 until tabs.tabCount){
            tabs.getTabAt(i)?.let {
                it.icon = ActivityCompat.getDrawable(this,tabIcons[i])
                if( it.isSelected){
                    it.text = tabTitles[i]
                }else{
                    it.text = null
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed internally and will go out with a new release of the material design library soon.

The gist of the problem is that internally, the selected tab isn't updated before `onTabUnselected()` is called. Then by setting the text for the tab in that method, it incorrectly updates the old selected tab as well.